# Modifying an Excel File in Google Drive with Apache POI

Tags: excel, google-drive-api, apache-poi

I need to modify some cells of an Excel file stored in Google Drive. I'm using Apache POI to manipulate the Excel file and I can read and modify the file, but when I commit it to Google Drive it seems to work, it returns a success code but the file is not changed in Drive. The function I'm using to save the file is:

```
ParcelFileDescriptor file=result.getDriveContents().getParcelFileDescriptor();
InputStream in=new FileInputStream(file.getFileDescriptor());
HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(in);
for(Componente c:listaComponentes){
    HSSFSheet sheet=wb.getSheetAt(c.getHoja());
    HSSFRow fila=sheet.getRow(c.getFila());
    fila.getCell(celdaSerie).setCellValue(c.getSerie());
}
FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(file.getFileDescriptor());
wb.write(fileOut);
result.getDriveContents().commit(mGoogleApiClient, null);
```

Comment: Are you sure that the google client you're using reads changes to the file when committing?

Comment: I'm using the oficial google drive client for the pc and I've checked in the web and in the Android App, always with the same result.